# Read and Write Parquet and HDFS files from java

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs, parquet

currently I can read and write HDFS files in java, but I don't know how to read apache parquet files besides hdfs, my idea is to be able to read and write both files in java

```
package com.leerhdfs;

//import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Progressable;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class ReadWriteHDFSExample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String localsrc = args[0];
    String destinosrc = args[1];

    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(localsrc));
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(destinosrc), conf);

    OutputStream out = fs.create(new Path(destinosrc), new Progressable() {

        public void progress() {
            System.out.println(".");

        }
    });

    IOUtils.copyBytes(in, out, 4096, true);
 }
```

}

Please help me!!!
Thanks!!

Comment: What is the relation to Apache Spark here?

Comment: And why don't you use a Parquet Java API if you want to read PArquet in Java? I mean, you did the same for HDFS, right? Also, what means "both files"? HDFS is a file system, Parquet a data/file format. You can also have Parquet files on an HDFS file system